# Can't mount a CIFS volume

Tags: macos, mount

I'm trying to mount a remote volume with cifs. Whenever I try to `mount -t cifs ...`, I get an error saying `mount_cifs` can't be found. Where can I find it? Or how do I install it?

I'm using OS X 10.9.2 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you´re looking for `mount_smbfs` :) or `mount -t smbfs ...`

Comment: Well, from an Ubuntu machine I use mount -t -cifs and not smbfs (cifs superseded it).

Comment: CIFS and SMBFS are the same but it depends on the manufacturer of a OS how he will spell it. And OSX are based on FreeBSD which called it SMB. If you need more details please have a look at [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: From Apple's manual page "Note: You should always use the system mount command and never call mount_smbfs directly." - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/mount_smbfs.8.html